# Drupal Token Examples of Usage

Tags: php, drupal, token

I need to include a node content in another node using some kind of placeholder, for example: `[node-5663]` will be translated to the node's content (body) where node-id matches 5663.

The example above is just an example, what I would need is actually something like this: `[table-TABLE-ID]` where `TABLE-ID` will be a field I define in the node (using CCK).

I don't have any problem searching and matching the content I need to fetch, but what I am missing is how to use the tokens.

Any help would be welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm a little fuzzy on the exact details of what you want, the basic premise is actually quite simple.

You will want to build a custom module, which simply defines some tokens, similar to the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_module' => array(
      'arguments' => array('object' => NULL)
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_token_list().
 */
function my_module_token_list($type = 'all') {
  if ($type == 'node' || $type == 'all') {
    $tokens = array();
    $tokens['my_module']['table-TABLE-ID'] = t('description').
    return $tokens;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_token_values().
 */
function my_module_token_values($type, $object = NULL) {
  if ($type == 'node') {
    ($table, $id) = explode('-', $object->my_field['value']);
    $tokens['table-' . $object->my_field['value']] = theme('my_module', db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT * FROM {" . $table . "} WHERE id = %d", $id)));
    return $tokens;
  }
}

function theme_my_module($object) {
  return '<div>' . $object->content . '</div>';
}
```

**Note:** All this code is theoretical and I can pretty much state that it will not work. It is also highly insecure to do the db_query the way I have done it here (which was my interpretation of what you wanted), instead you should have a token for each different type of query you want ('table-node-ID', etc).

Hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: As a side note, if the token itself where to be placed the Body field you would also need the Token Filter module (http://drupal.org/project/token_filter) to translate the token.

Comment: The answer is for Drupal 6. In Drupal 7, "hook_token_list() is now [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7), and hook_token_values() is now [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7)", says the [update log page](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token/update/6/7).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access tokens from another module within php, a quick way to do that is with the drupal function "token_replace($text)"

You pass it text that may contain the token and it will return text with the token replaced.

example for Drupal 7

```
<?php
$tokentext = "I'm the ga_tokenizer:ga-term [ga_tokenizer:ga-term]";
$processedText = token_replace($tokentext);
print $processedText;
?>
```

This will output 
**I'm the ga_tokenizer:ga-term THE SEARCH TERM USED TO FIND THE PAGE**

If you just want the actual token value, use

```
<?php
$tokentext = "[ga_tokenizer:ga-term]";
$processedText = token_replace($tokentext);
?>
```

Comment: Those `[ga_tokenizer:*]` tokens only work if the [Google Analytics Tokenizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga_tokenizer) module is enabled. See that module, or [Decipher's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2270062) above for how to define your own tokens before use.